# Permutation index

Tags: list-manipulation

Inside of a list I have three values

```
distancias={184.098,180.278,211.218}
```

These can be easily sorted from small to large:

```
seq=Sort[distancias]
```

Is there any function where I can get a list of indexes that shows the position of the child to the highest value in the original list?

I did it this way, but I do not like to use so much function:

```
Flatten[Position [distancias,seq[[#]]&/@Range[Length[distancias]]]
```

Comment: Look up [`Ordering`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ordering)

Comment: Seems to me to be this